# Connect Desktop to iOS Device via Java

Tags: java, ios

So I wondered if there is a way to establish a connection between my iOS Device (mainly iPhone/iPad) and my Java Application so that I can acces Files  like Music, Pictures, etc. like many Applications already do (CopyTransManager, SharePod, ...). If there is a simple way, maybe also with another Language (C++, C#, whatever) I would be glad if you could tell me, or give a bit of information so that I can look by myself :)

Thank you already! :)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html <> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html

Comment: @zapl which would still need an ios app to run on the phone in order to connect the two sockets am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that would need an application of yours on both ends. I don't know how those apps you mention work.#